# How can I upload a specific field massivel in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sql-loader, ctl

I have a table as following with more fields but not put all.

Table:

```
id_service
id_date_suscription
id_date_unsuscription
..
```

I have a ctl with which insert data `id_date_suscription` filling the field and everyone else, but leaving nul `id_date_unsuscription` field in another file I have the information to update the field `id_date_unsuscription`, but not if a ctl I can do, or that another no way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You'd find this easier with an external table load, as the second file can be loaded with a merge statement that updates the rows loaded from the first, or you could join the data from the two files together in SQL and perform a single insert. The latter approach would probably be the most efficient.